# Extension of Inverse Function Theorem from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inverse-function-theorem

Consider the *Inverse Function Theorem* in $\mathbb{R}$:

Let $O ∈\mathbb{R}$ be open for $f:O → \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is *continuously differentiable*, and for a $x_0 ∈O$, $f'\left(x_0\right) \ne 0$. Then there exist an open interval $\boldsymbol{I}$ about $x_0$ and open interval $\boldsymbol{J}$ about the image of $f\left(x_0\right)$ such that
$ f: \boldsymbol{I} → \boldsymbol{J}$ is *one to one* and *onto*. Futhermore, $f^{-1}: \boldsymbol{J} → \boldsymbol{I}$ is *continuously differentiable*, and if $y ∈\boldsymbol{J}$, $x ∈\boldsymbol{I}$ such that $f\left(x\right) = y$, then
\begin{split}
(f^{-1})'(y) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}
\end{split}

Compared with the *Inverse Function Theorem* in $\mathbb{R^n}$:

Let $O ∈\mathbb{R^n}$ be open for $\boldsymbol{F}:O → \mathbb{R^n}$. If $\boldsymbol{F}$ is *continuously differentiable*, and for a $\boldsymbol{x_*} ∈O$,  $\boldsymbol{DF}\left(\boldsymbol{x_*}\right)$ is *invertible*. Then there exist a neighborhood $\boldsymbol{I}$ about $\boldsymbol{x_*}$ and an neighborhood $\boldsymbol{J}$ about the image of $\boldsymbol{F}\left(\boldsymbol{x_*}\right)$ such that
$ \boldsymbol{F}: \boldsymbol{I} → \boldsymbol{J}$ is *one to one* and *onto*. Futhermore, $\boldsymbol{F}^{-1}: \boldsymbol{J} → \boldsymbol{I}$ is *continuously differentiable*, and if $\boldsymbol{y} ∈\boldsymbol{J}$, $\boldsymbol{x} ∈\boldsymbol{I}$ such that $\boldsymbol{F}\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right) = \boldsymbol{y}$, then
\begin{split}
\boldsymbol{DF}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{y}) = [\boldsymbol{DF}(\boldsymbol{x})]^{-1}
\end{split}

I noticed that for the *Inverse Function Theorem* in $\mathbb{R^n}$, it is possible for all $\boldsymbol{x} ∈O$  $(O ∈\mathbb{R^n})$ to satisfy the requirements of the theorem, yet still have $\boldsymbol{F}: O → \mathbb{R^n}$ be **not** *one to one*. For example:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{F}(x,y) = \left(e^x\cos \left(y\right),e^x\sin \left(y\right)\right)
\end{equation}
$\boldsymbol{F}$ is *continuously differentiable*, and for any $\boldsymbol{x} ∈\mathbb{R^n}$, the *determinant* of $\boldsymbol{DF}\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)$ does not equal to $0$. Yet, $\boldsymbol{F}$ is **not** *one to one* (e.g. the points $\left(0,0\right)$ and $\left(0,2π\right)$ produce the same result). This, I presume, is due to the fact that the *Inverse Function Theorem* is only true for the functon $\boldsymbol{F}$ on its restrictions (from $\boldsymbol{I}$ to $\boldsymbol{J}$).

**Question:**

1) Could this also happen for the *Inverse Function Theorem* in $\mathbb{R}$? That is, could $f: O → \mathbb{R}$ be *continuously differentiable*, and $f'\left(x\right) \ne 0$ for all $x ∈\mathbb{R}$, yet still have $f: O → \mathbb{R}$ be **not** *one to one*? If no, why are they different?

2) Could this also happen to the *onto* property of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be explicit, I am taking continuous differentiability here to mean that the the function is continuous, and has a continuous first derivative.

If $f^\prime (x) \neq 0$ for all $x\in O$ by continuity it must be the case that $f^\prime (x)>0$ for all $x\in O$ or $f^\prime (x) <0$ for all $x\in O$.

In either case, $f$ is strictly monotonic and hence must be one-to-one.

This function may not be onto. Consider any affine function defined on an open interval that is not the entire real line.

I don't have a good explanation for why the difference, but my suspicion is that, in multiple dimensions, you can have saddle/inflection points in some dimensions but still have the Jacobian be invertible. However, this is decidedly not the case in one variable.

Comment: That doesn't satisfy the requirement that $f'(x) \ne 0$ for **all** $x$

Comment: Yes, of course. Was being sloppy. Apologies.

Comment: @thestateofmay Answer edited.